# when creating new attributes getting an error

Tags: magento2, customer, magento2.2, customer-attribute

I created the module. Everything is working fine but when click on add to new attribute button this error coming. Can you please anyone help me.

```
    1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException): Invalid template file: 'Tychons_CustomerAttribute::Customer/attribute/labels.phtml' in module: 'Tychons_CustomerAttribute' block's name: 'attribute_edit_tabs_schedule_block4'

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException): Invalid template file: 'Tychons_CustomerAttribute::Customer/attribute/labels.phtml' in module: 'Tychons_CustomerAttribute' block's name: 'attribute_edit_tabs_schedule_block4'
#0 /var/www/html/inciteenergy/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(300): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView(false)
```

Comment: Have you read the error!!? It's telling you what's wrong.

Comment: in this module I didn't create the attribute_edit_tabs_schedule_block4

Answer (score 0):

Find in source where: `attribute_edit_tabs_schedule_block4` is located.
Try `attribute_edit_tabs_schedule_block` (no 4 on end).
Check `Block` directory in `Tychons_CustomerAttribute`. There is something like that? Also check if disabling this component help. You get more specific context to look for error.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But it's not working.